# SQL Server CASE, select table columns

Tags: sql-server, select, case

I'm wondering if its possible to change this code and use a CASE instead:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spName
    @Tabla varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Tabla = 'Cargos'
       SELECT IdCargo, Cargo 
       FROM Cargos 

    IF @Tabla = 'Proveedores'
       SELECT IdProveedor, Proveedor, IdCiudad 
       FROM Proveedores 

    --And 4 more IF statements...
END
```

I've reading for a while but I found nothing, all the examples of `CASE` statements get only 1 value and I want the `CASE` to perform different queries depending on the value of parameter received. Is it possible to use a CASE statement here? If so, how?

P.D. I use these queries to populate DataTables in C# but I want all these queries in the same stored procedure.

Comment: You *could* use dynamic sql to construct a single SELECT statement, but going by your example each query is totally different so you wouldn't gain any coding efficiency. I'd say just stick with what you've got if that's the case (no pun intended).

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is **not** a statement - it's an **expression** (like `a+b`) which returns a single atomic value. It **cannot** be used to conditionally execute code blocks - so **NO**, `CASE` would definitely not be a good choice here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Although, as per my understanding this is not a good idea to have a generic sp for all your tables because sometimes you need to write business logic and different where clause condition.
on the same time as your different table has different columns so it is not possible to use case.
Although, to resolve your single stored procedure aim you can write dynamic query as shown below

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE myGenericProc 
    @tableName VARCHAR(100),
    @ColumnName VARCHAR(500) -- Comma seperated columns or * 
AS
    BEGIN
   DECLARE @SQLQuery VARCHAR(1000)
   SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT ' + @ColumnName +' FROM ' + @tableName
       Execute(@SQLQuery)
End
```